# socket auto buffer size

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

I'm trying to make a C# socket client but when i create a buffer size with 256

```
public class StateObject
{
    // Size of receive buffer.
    public const int BufferSize = 256; // the buffer size :/
    // Receive buffer.
    public byte[] Buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
    // Received data string.
    public StringBuilder Sb = new StringBuilder();
    public Socket WorkSocket = null;
}
```

i miss some received buffers and begin received as a separated buffer array,
if i create it for example a 1000 buffer size i'm wasting too many memory if i'm receiving a buffer with low size is there any way to make the buffer size auto ?

this is the code i'm using for connect call back and receive call back

```
    private void OnConnectCallBack(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        Socket.EndConnect(ar);
        Connection = Connection.Connected;
        if (OnConnect != null) OnConnect(this, CONNECTION_FROM.CLIENT);
        // Begin receiving the data from the remote device.
        Socket.BeginReceive(State.Buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, OnReceiveCallBack, State);
    }

    private void OnReceiveCallBack(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        int bytesRead = Socket.EndReceive(ar);
        // There might be more data, so store the data received so far.
        if (OnReceive != null) OnReceive(this, State.Buffer, CONNECTION_FROM.CLIENT);
        // Get the rest of the data.
        Socket.BeginReceive(State.Buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
            OnReceiveCallBack, State);
    }
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: You are missing the extraction part of the code, share it with us so we could help you.

Comment: There's nothing such as "auto" buffer size.
Why don't you use a fixed-length length-specifier bytes at the beginning of the "message" which specifies the length of the message, and then append the message?